# Arrays of Arrays in JSON

Tags: json

I'm a little new to JSON syntax. I'm trying to learn it correctly. I have a scenario where I have an array of objects. Each object has two properties which themselves are arrays. The root object is called "Department". Each Department has "Managers" and "Employees". At this point, I have the following, but I'm stuck:

```
var departments = {
  "data": [

  ]
};
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: for the next time, create the structure you want, say in PHP, and then json_encode it and echo it to see how it looks like.

Comment: Using arrays as top level in your JSON objects is really not recommendable, as it is highly insecure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not JSON, the structure you describe looks something like this in JSON:

```
[{"managers":["John"],"employees":["Peter","Maria"]},{"managers":["Anna"],"employees":["Philip","Jane"]}]
```

The root object is just an array, it doesn't have a name.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is an array of objects, each having two array properties:

```
[
  {prop1: [ ... ], prop2: [ ... ]},
  {prop1: [ ... ], prop2: [ ... ]}
]
```

hope that helps.